# google mock multiple EXPECT_CALL conflict with each other?

Tags: c++, googletest, conflict, googlemock

I've got this code snippet and it runs well:

```
class If2{
public:
    virtual void set(const char* s)=0;
};
class Impl2:public If2{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(set, void(const char*));
};
TEST(t2,case2){
    Impl2 mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock,set).Times(Between(1,5));
    mock.set("aa");
}
```

But when I add 2 EXPECT_CALL for set(), then it doesn't work:

```
TEST(t2,case2){
    Impl2 mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock,set).Times(Between(1,5));
    EXPECT_CALL(mock,set(Not(HasSubstr("bb"))));
    mock.set("aa");
}
```

Error message is:

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mock, set)...
        Expected: to be called between 1 and 5 times
        Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

It's really strange for me, I've called "set" once, why multiple EXPECT_CALL doesn't work here?
Thanks.

Comment: Only last matcher wins. so your test would pass only if you call also `mock("..bb..")` 1-5 times.

Comment: Maybe you want `EXPECT_CALL(mock,set(Not(HasSubstr("bb")))).Times(Between(1,5));`.